# Wordpress custom post type capabilities, admin can't edit post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm having a wired problem with WordPress. Below is my code for an events post type, it works without the capabilities but when the capabilities are added all the default roles (admin, editor, etc...) cant use the post type. The admin role is only able to see the custom taxonomies.

I have a custom user role with "edit_events => true" for the user role that is able to submit events for review. This is what I want, but the built in roles can't see the post type!

I've tried just about every capabilities tutorial I could find, they all seem to be pretty much the same and I can't how any of them differ from my code.

```
function register_custom_event_type() {
$labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Events', 'event'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Event', 'event'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'event'),
    'add_new_item' => _x('Add New Event', 'event'),
    'edit_item' => _x('Edit Event', 'event'),
    'new_item' => _x('New Event', 'event'),
    'view_item' => _x('View Event', 'event'),
    'search_items' => _x('Search Events', 'event'),
    'not_found' => _x('No events found', 'event'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => _x('No events found in Trash', 'event'),
    'parent_item_colon' => _x('Parent Event:', 'event'),
    'menu_name' => _x('Events', 'event'),
);

$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'author'),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'can_export' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'event',
    'capabilities' => array(
            'read_post' => 'read_event',
            'publish_posts' => 'publish_events',
            'edit_posts' => 'edit_events',
            'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_others_events',
            'delete_posts' => 'delete_events',
            'delete_others_posts' => 'delete_others_events',
            'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_events',
            'edit_post' => 'edit_event',
            'delete_post' => 'delete_event',

        ),
    'map_meta_cap' => true
);
register_post_type('event', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'register_custom_event_type');
```

Answer (score 9):

I found a work around in the end.

I thought the default WordPress Roles would have the same capabilities for the post type as a normal post, but for some reason they don't.

Adding the capabilities manually seems to work.

```
function add_event_caps() {
  $role = get_role( 'administrator' );
  $role->add_cap( 'edit_event' ); 
  $role->add_cap( 'edit_events' ); 
  $role->add_cap( 'edit_others_events' ); 
  $role->add_cap( 'publish_events' ); 
  $role->add_cap( 'read_event' ); 
  $role->add_cap( 'read_private_events' ); 
  $role->add_cap( 'delete_event' ); 
  $role->add_cap( 'edit_published_events' );   //added
  $role->add_cap( 'delete_published_events' ); //added
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_event_caps');
```

Comment: Don't forget: `$role->add_cap( 'edit_published_events' );` and `$role->add_cap( 'delete_published_events' );`

Answer (score 6):

make sure to include
`'map_meta_cap' => true,` when registering your custom post type also set the capability type correctly eg. `'capability_type' => array('event', 'events'),` then use the [User Role Editor Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) and click the permissions as you see fit for the individual roles - done!

Answer (score 1):

After setting `'map_meta_cap' => true` and setting `'capability_type' => array('event', 'events')` you might also need to add the capabilities:

> There are also eight other primitive capabilities which are not referenced directly in core, except in map_meta_cap(), which takes the three aforementioned meta capabilities and translates them into one or more primitive capabilities that must then be checked against the user or role, depending on the context. These additional capabilities are only used in map_meta_cap(). Thus, they are only assigned by default if the post type is registered with the 'map_meta_cap' argument set to true (default is false).

```
read - Controls whether objects of this post type can be read.
delete_posts - Controls whether objects of this post type can be deleted.
delete_private_posts - Controls whether private objects can be deleted.
delete_published_posts - Controls whether published objects can be deleted.
delete_others_posts - Controls whether objects owned by other users can be can be deleted. If the post type does not support an author, then this will behave like delete_posts.
edit_private_posts - Controls whether private objects can be edited.
edit_published_posts - Controls whether published objects can be edited.
create_posts - Controls whether new objects can be created
```

[register_post_type() Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

Answer (score 0):

thats a strange problem. it should work. the following will work for you (note i just copied paste my code so some of my code creeped in)

```
add_action('init', 'register_custom_event_type');
function register_custom_event_type() {
  register_post_type('event',
    array(
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => _x('Event', 'Event'),
      'singular_name' => _x('Event Custom Post', 'domain'),
      'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'domain'),
      'add_new_item' => _x('Add New Event Custom Post', 'domain'),
      'edit' => _x('Edit', 'domain'),
      'edit_item' => _x('Edit Event Custom Post', 'domain'),
      'new_item' => _x('New Event Custom Post', 'domain'),
      'view' => _x('View Event Custom Post', 'domain'),
      'view_item' => _x('View Event Custom Post', 'domain'),
      'search_items' => _x('Search Event Custom Post', 'domain'),
      'not_found' => _x('No Event Custom Posts found', 'domain'),
      'not_found_in_trash' => _x('No Event Custom Posts found in Trash', 'domain')
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail' ),
    'can_export' => true,
    'taxonomies' => array( 'category' ),
    'register_meta_box_cb' => '',
    'map_meta_cap' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'event',
    'capabilities' => array(
      'read_post' => 'read_event',
      'publish_posts' => 'publish_events',
      'edit_posts' => 'edit_events',
      'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_others_events',
      'delete_posts' => 'delete_events',
      'delete_others_posts' => 'delete_others_events',
      'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_events',
      'edit_post' => 'edit_event',
      'delete_post' => 'delete_event',
     ),
  ));
}
```

Something to do with the way you are calling it. Dont know where. sometimes its easier just to start again :)

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've tried your code and I still have the same issue. I've also commented out all the other code in the plugin so it's just the above code and I still have the same problem. If I remove the capability_type and capabilities it works fine! Going to try a clean WordPress install, make sure there are no other affecting affecting it.

Comment: well i was using wp 3.6 (should have mentioned it). the code you posted didnt work in my fresh install of wp3.6, except, as like you, removing the capabilities portion then it worked. the code i posted worked for me. what wp version are you running?

Comment: Also another plugin could be causing issues. deactivate all to see if the register_post_type works, then re-enable each plugin one by one. maybe try the p3-profiler plugin to see which plugins are being called.

Comment: I'm on wp 3.6. Just tried a clean install with just your code and the admin user can't see the post type. I'm so confused!

Comment: Just starter over with code from here, http://themergency.com/generators/wordpress-custom-post-types/ Still the same issue! Clean wordpress install, different hosting, remove capabilities and it works.

Comment: I know this thread is really old, but I stumbled on it while looking for answers.

With regards to the problem mentioned, you needs to use both the single and the plural name when adding the capability as mentioned by McKean above:

`'capability_type' => array('event', 'events'),`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Custom capability_type in custom post type, logged in as user with new user role is no problem, but the admin did not see the articles in CPT.

Installing "User Role Editor" did the trick. Acivating, Reload, Deactivating, Deleting. Still works.

Answer (score -2):

When registering the post type, add the supports tag enabling editor like this:
`'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt' )`

Comment: what is that with regard to question?